# How do I resolve a file conflict with a file that is marked for deletion in subversion?

Tags: svn

Background:

- Server Box 1: ONLY checks out repositories from SVN (production)
- Server Box 2: Developers work on in individual sand boxes and commit to SVN. (Development)
- Server Box 3: SVN Repository

Sequence of events:

1. Developer 1: worked directly on server box 1.
2. Developer 1: Realized mistake then copied to server box 2 and tried to commit to SVN Server and failed.
3. Developer 2: Noticed a problem performing a checkout and manually deleted the file from OS.
4. Developer 2: Noticed still unable to check out from server box 2, manually added the file back to the os, and deleted via SVN.
5. Developer 2: Stuck in mud with what looks like an un-resolveable conflict.

The file is marked for deletion in Server box 1.  The correct version is sitting in SVN repository, but developers are unable to checkout that file due to a conflict "U".  How can this conflict be resolved? (without deleting and performing a whole new checkout?) SVN does not prompt for conflict resolution when performing a checkout any more.

All Servers are running command line ONLY Linux. (no gui clients...)

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
:>svn status
...
!     C path/filename.ext
      >   local delete, incoming edit upon update
...
```

Comment: do the commands 'svn info' or 'svn status' yield any interesting information?  You may have to manually edit a tree conflict.

Comment: How does one manually edit a tree conflict?

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a tree conflict.  Here's the svn book's [section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html) on how to deal with them.